# How to hide the url we are posting data to through a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, controller

I have the below button in my view.

```
<%= button_to('On', @userdetail.url + '?value=1', :method => "post", :remote => true, :disable_with => 'loading...') %>
```

`@userdetail.url` is a external url which is not a part of my applcation. If somebody will see the source, will be able to see the url I am posting data to. 
Is there any way I can hide the URl from view?

I also want to exspose the button action as a API. Like if somebody will call localhost:3000/button action, it should send value 1 to the external URL.
Is there any way I can expose button action as a API rather than exposing the url to be used by other-clients.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to hide the external url if you let it onto the client side. But you can hide it by posting to your own server-side controller-action, and then posting to it from that action.

The same goes for doing this as an API-style call. Just create a server-side action that responds to that route, and let that action do the posting.

Comment: Could you please share a example controller action which does post to a external URL. I have been trying to create a controller action for the same but not able to do so. I tried using curl in my controller action and used that controller action in my button_to, but couldn't make it work.

Comment: `curl` should work, although the Ruby way is to use `Net::HTTP.post`. You should make sure that your action is actually being called.